# Python, code works, but openning via bat file get error

Tags: python

Following is a simple working GUI programm. However, when I try to open it from a `bat` file, it gives an error.

Bat file (2 lines):

```
ch10.2.py
pause
```

The error I receive is:

[error message in text format to be included here]

My code:

```
# Lazy Buttons 2
# Demonstrates using a class with Tkinter

from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """ A GUI application with three buttons. """ 
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the Frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)    
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create three buttons that do nothing. """
        # create first button
        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text = "I do nothing!")
        self.bttn1.grid()

        # create second button
        self.bttn2 = Button(self)
        self.bttn2.grid()   
        self.bttn2.configure(text = "Me too!")

        # create third button
        self.bttn3 = Button(self)
        self.bttn3.grid()
        self.bttn3["text"] = "Same here!"

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Buttons 2")
root.geometry("200x85")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the error? And what's the exact command you use to run it without error, and do you have both 2.x and 3.x installed.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of text in your posts - paste the actual error here.

Comment: Maybe your main interprenter is not Python 3.5? 2.7 or something older?

Comment: does your .bat file need to start with `python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving error on `super(Application, self).__init__(master)`.
If you replace with `Frame.__init__(self, master)` , its working.
See below

```
# Lazy Buttons 2
# Demonstrates using a class with Tkinter

from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """ A GUI application with three buttons. """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the Frame. """       
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #super(Application, self).__init__(master) 
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()




    def createWidgets(self):
        """ Create three buttons that do nothing. """
        # create first button
        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text = "I do nothing!")  
        self.bttn1.grid()

        # create second button
        self.bttn2 = Button(self)
        self.bttn2.grid()   
        self.bttn2.configure(text = "Me too!")

        # create third button
        self.bttn3 = Button(self)
        self.bttn3.grid()
        self.bttn3["text"] = "Same here!"


# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Buttons 2")
root.geometry("200x85")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Thank you the problem was in that t have 2.7 and 3.5 versions)